# Build debug configuration from the command line

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

When I run `/gradlew :android:tasks`, the output includes

```
Rules
-----
Pattern: clean<TaskName>: Cleans the output files of a task.
Pattern: build<ConfigurationName>: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
Pattern: upload<ConfigurationName>: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belonging to a configuration.
```

(Note: my app's module is named `android` rather than the default `app`.)

But when I do `./gradlew :android:buildDebug`, I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'buildDebug' not found in project ':android'.
```

Besides the default debug and release build configurations, I also have two flavors declared in `build.gradle`. How do I determine what are valid replacements for `<ConfigurationName>` in the instructions given by `/gradlew :android:tasks`?